# Running an exe file on premises from azure scheduler?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-scheduler

I want to be able to run an exe file in an on premises server from Azure, using a Logic app or maybe azure scheduler.

Is this possible, if so how?

Even doing this via Azure function could be an option. Do i need something like on premises data gateway or maybe even hybrid connections?

Comment: For Cloud service, I think you can use **worker role** to meet your requirement. Worker role could handle background processor. Also, you can use the startup task to run your exe.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add it as a comment, but I do not have reputation to do that.
So, my hypothesis is you can do that with Logic apps, you have to deploy the API in on-premises server and the exe application in same server. Then with "process" you can invoke that console application with API and that API you can call it from Azure Logic Apps

But I have not tried it. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

**(Update 06/26/2023)** What I did was, hosted an API in IIS server and from API I called console application, which was suppose to change AD data, and it worked fine.

I have to host the api in order to test it from Logic apps, but it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, Azure Scheduler and Logic App don't support `.exe` file.

For Cloud service, I think you can use **worker role** to meet your requirement. Worker role could handle background processor. Also, you can use the startup task to run your exe.

You can see a example in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common).

Comment: hmm, so there is no way to do this in the portal without using visual studio so to speak? Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Yes, I think the best practice is using The Worker role to achieve your requirement.  If this answer is helpful to you , please mark it as answer so that we can help more people. Thanks!